# "Unreachable Network" After network bonding

Tags: linux-networking, bonding

We've configured network bonding on more than 20 VM. It is working properly but after this configuration VM's fall from network in random order and conditions. Restarting network service is solving the situation but after a while it's happening again. Here is the master-bond conf

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0
BONDING_OPTS="ad_select=stable all_slaves_active=0 arp_all_targets=any downdelay=0 fail_over_mac=none lp_interval=1 miimon=100 min_links=0 mode=balance-alb num_grat_arp=1 num_unsol_na=1 primary_reselect=always resend_igmp=1 updelay=0 use_carrier=1 xmit_hash_policy=layer2"
BONDING_MASTER=yes
TYPE=Bond
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
UUID=some-uuid
DEVICE=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=.67
PREFIX=24
DEFROUTE=yes
GATEWAY=.199.254
DNS1=.199.254
```

nmcli output:

```
# nmcli d
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
bond0   bond      connected  Bond bond0
ens32   ethernet  connected  System ens32
ens34   ethernet  connected  System ens34
ens35   ethernet  connected  System ens35
ens36   ethernet  connected  System ens36
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

I'm not able to get dmesg output at the moment, but i'll try to add it.

**UPDATE**
We've found that if a slave which has the same mac address of the bond-master and when the slave fais, bond fails.

Comment: Is there a reason that the slave has a duped MAC address?

Comment: Yes it is active slave, it's like master of slaves, it depends on the fail_over_mac parameter, you can set master's mac constant or dynamic.